# How to check installed TWRP version?

Tags: twrp, bash

I’d like to know if there is a way to check what version of TWRP is installed using `bash` (using a file or command in Android).

I could find `/persist/.twrps` only, which is data file. No command I have found.

Comment: Read `.twrps` with `strings` but it contains only TWRP settings, not version. I don't think it's possible without booting to recovery.

Comment: If you have taken any backup and is still stored inside internal storage, you can look for the string "ro.twrp.version" in the recovery.log for the backup.

Comment: @Firelord, thank you. Nice workaround, however, I’d rather don’t want rely on `recovery.log` as (1) it does not exist all the time TWRP is installed and (2) it might contain older version of TWRP when you create a backup and then upgrade the TWRP.