# How to determine which version of TWRP has been installed?

Tags: rooting, root-access, twrp, htc, android-versions

A secondhand phone looks to have `TWRP` already installed:

```
thufir@dur:/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=HTC_Android_Phone_SH4AYWM01306/Internal storage$ 
thufir@dur:/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=HTC_Android_Phone_SH4AYWM01306/Internal storage$ ll
total 53
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir    0 Dec 31  1969 ./
dr-x------ 1 thufir thufir    0 Dec 31  1969 ../
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Oct 26  2019 Alarms/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Oct 26  2019 Android/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 26  2019 .data/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Dec 18  2019 DCIM/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Oct 26  2019 Download/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Oct 26  2019 Movies/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Oct 26  2019 Music/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Oct 26  2019 _nero_sync/
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir   38 Oct 26  2019 nmdsdcid
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Oct 26  2019 Notifications/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Mar 31 17:31 Pictures/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Oct 26  2019 Podcasts/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir    0 Oct 26  2019 Ringtones/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir    0 Apr 12 13:34 .showme/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Mar  4 14:34 TWRP/
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Nov 27  2019 WhatsApp/
thufir@dur:/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=HTC_Android_Phone_SH4AYWM01306/Internal storage$ 
thufir@dur:/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=HTC_Android_Phone_SH4AYWM01306/Internal storage$ ll TWRP/
total 5
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir 4096 Mar  4 14:34 ./
drwx------ 1 thufir thufir    0 Dec 31  1969 ../
-rw------- 1 thufir thufir  973 Apr 12 13:27 .twrps
thufir@dur:/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=HTC_Android_Phone_SH4AYWM01306/Internal storage$
```

How do I determine which the version number for `TWRP` which is already installed?

Comment: If it is a second hand phone I would not trust any pre-installed software at all. Just download the latest TWRP for your device and install it.

Comment: this is exactly my concern @Robert -- thanks.

Comment: [How to check installed TWRP version?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/216439/218526)